# Metabox image upload and custom field

Tags: custom-field, metabox, uploads

Is it possible to
a) upload image in meta box (not using default WP image uploader) and then
b) get the path to uploaded this way image in a custom field?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should help: http://austinpassy.com/2010/03/creating-custom-metaboxes-and-the-built-in-uploader/